# Getting Location Data from connected WIFI Network device

Tags: ios, swift

I’m new at working with WIFI Network connected devices so please excuse my ignorance.  I need to be able to receive GPS location data via the GDL90 protocol from a WIFI connected external GPS and integrate that into my app.

How do I access the data? JSON? Other? I’ve looked at the GDL90 protocol and am not seeing anything that stands out as a starting point. Again, I’ve not worked with network data so I’m not sure what I know or don’t know.

Once I’ve figured out how to access and read the data, I’ll be good from there, but I’ve hit a wall.

Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use CoreLocation?

Comment: The app does use CoreLocation. However, for iPad’s that don’t have the internal GPS I would like to get the GPS externally. It also gets me access to a whole bunch of other data that the external hardware might provide.

Comment: Some external GPS devices work with iOS natively and Core Location simply uses their data once the device is configured with iOS. I think this may be wth Bluetooth devices, however.  GDL 90 is just the data format. You need to look at the specifics of your device to understand how it exposes that data. Via a web service? Via a TCP network socket?  Once you understand that then you can come up with an approach it read it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The device exposes the data through UDP ports and IP access points. So my assumption is that it’s a UDP  network socket.

Answer (score 0):

Following this Apple documentation using CoreLocation will answer all your technical questions:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/

Comment: Thanks. I’m already using CoreLocation and have no issues getting location data from the internal GPS (when available). I specifically want to be able to get data from an external WiFi connected unit. I reviewed Apple’s documentation and didn’t find anything related to that. Am I missing something?